# Changing the skybox via script in unity makes all the gameObjects in the scene super dark

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, skybox

I want to change the skybox in my game through script depending on what skybox the player has chosen.
Here's the code for that

```
 if(SaveGame.Load<string>("Map").Contains("Night"))
        {
            dayLight.SetActive(false);
            nightLight.SetActive(true);
            RenderSettings.skybox =skyboxes[1];
        }
        else if(SaveGame.Load<string>("Map").Contains("Day"))
        {
            dayLight.SetActive(true);
            nightLight.SetActive(false);
            RenderSettings.skybox =skyboxes[0];
        }
```

I can confirm that the error is not in the
`SaveGame.Load<string>("Map)` because it actually does change the skybox. It changes it from night to day. However all the gameobjects in my scene become super dim and black. The only way I fix this is by dragging the skybox material from the Project tab to the scene view, everything becomes shiny again, but when I do it from script it's super dark. There are also no errors at all in the Console. How do I fix this?

Comment: Remove all the set actives to see if it changes anything

Comment: Are you using Dynamic GI?

Comment: @MiladQasemi I removed all the set actives and nothing changed. I'm not too experienced with Dynamic GI but I'm making an android game so I'm not sure if I can use it with that without destroying performance.

Comment: I meant if you are using GI you should use `DynamicGI.UpdateEnvironment();` after changing skybox

Comment: @MiladQasemi Oh my goodness I'm such an idiot. Thank you so much! This has been driving me insane for quite a bit. I really appreciate it!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If **Dynamic Global Illumination (Dynamic GI)** is used the environment cube map needs to be updated after changing the skybox. it can be done like this:

```
DynamicGI.UpdateEnvironment();
```